# jquery not working for dropdown menu? (Chromium)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a webpage where the options in the second dropdown menu depend on the value selected in the first dropdown menu. However, when running the webpage, the options in the second dropdown do not change regardless of what is selected in the first dropdown. The Browser does indicate that it SEES the javascript file, but it just doesn't appear to be actually running it for some reason. Anyone know what's going on?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

$convertfrom = $("select[name='ConvertFrom']");
$convertto = $("select[name='ConvertTo']");

$convertto.change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == "Binary") {
    $("select[name='convertto'] option").remove();
    $("<option>Decimal</option>").appendTo($convertto);
    $("<option>Octal</option>").appendTo($convertto);
    $("<option>HexaDecimal</option>").appendTo($convertto);
  }

  if ($(this).val() == "Decimal") {
    $("select[name='convertto'] option").remove();
    $("<option>Binary</option>").appendTo($convertto);
    $("<option>Octal</option>").appendTo($convertto);
    $("<option>HexaDecimal</option>").appendTo($convertto);
  }

  if ($(this).val() == "Octal") {
    $("select[name='convertto'] option").remove();
    $("<option>Binary</option>").appendTo($convertto);
    $("<option>Decimal</option>").appendTo($convertto);
    $("<option>HexaDecimal</option>").appendTo($convertto);
  }

  if ($(this).val() == "HexaDecimal") {
    $("select[name='convertto'] option").remove();
    $("<option>Binary</option>").appendTo($convertto);
    $("<option>Decimal</option>").appendTo($convertto);
    $("<option>Octal</option>").appendTo($convertto);
  }

});

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <title>Practice</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p> Welcome to the Practice Page. On this page, you can randomly generate a problem and see if you can solve it correctly.
  Please select a base to convert from below. You'll then be asked to select a base to convert to, and then given a problem to solve. </p>

  <form>
    <select id="ConvertFrom">
      <option value="Select">Select</option>
      <option value="Binary">Binary</option>
      <option value="Decimal">Decimal</option>
      <option value="Octal">Octal</option>
      <option value="HexaDecimal">HexaDecimal</option>
    </select>

    <select id="ConvertTo">
      <option value="Convertto">ConvertTo</option>
    </select>
  </form>
<script src="file:///C:/Users/johnt/Documents/Catan/practice2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You made four mistakes.

1. `$convertfrom = $("select[name='ConvertFrom']");` has to be `$('#ConvertFrom');`
2. `$convertto = $("select[name='ConvertTo']");` has to be `$('#ConvertTo');`
3. `$convertto.change(function() {` has to be `$convertfrom.change(function() {`
4. `$("select[name='convertto'] option").remove()` has to be `$convertto.innerHTML = '';`

Comment: This mostly works, but my $("select[name='#ConvertTo'] option").remove(); commands are not working. This is supposed to remove all current options from the second dropdown before adding the new options, but it does not currently do anything. This is bad because if the user selects "Decimal" in the first dropdown and then changes their mind to "Binary", they will get a six option dropdown menu, when it should simply be a different three option dropdown menu.

Comment: You haven't followed `4.`.